# tensorflow object detection API training and export graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have the following problem: When I retrain the TF object detection API with my own dataset, the training is often killed and I don't know the reason. there is no errors log, just killed.
Moreover, why in my `MODEL_DIR` only few `model.ckpt-XXXX` are saved?

Secondly, when I try to export the above model to a frozen graph with the provided script, I saw in the analysis that there is incomplete shape:

```
================== Model Analysis Report ======================
Incomplete shape.
```

I used a `model.cpkt-XXXX` after the training process got killed, is it the reason why the shape is incomplete?

The exported model can be use for inference but I guess it is not optimal...

FYI, I have retrained the mobileSSDv2 with 1 class and I have modified the pipeline config file regarding the changes as follow:

- I change number of class to 1
- in train `config {}` part, I changed batch size to 12 and put the number of steps to 200
- `train_input_reader` and `eval_input_reader {}` parts, I have added my path the the TF record and `labelmap.pbtxt`
- in `eval_config {}` part, I have changed the number of example to 85 ( the number of picture in my eval images repository) and max eval to 5.

I use ubuntu 16.04 with tensoflow-GPU 1.12.0 in a virtualenv with python 2.7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tensorflow-gpu and you have a GPU, **200 is a really low number**, that you reach in less few minutes (and your conv-net will learn nothing). Increase it to 100.000, at least.

Moreover, due to the low number of training steps, you might expect that training save your model at start (step 0) and end training (step 200), so you get only 2 models.

Tensorflow save models every 600 seconds, if you don't change **save_interval_secs** inside *trainer.py*